# Negative position:absolute causes horizontal scroll on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, css-position, horizontal-scrolling

I've added a sidebar tab "Subscribe" (jquery.tabSlideOut.v1.3.js) to my site (visit http://thecasket.co.uk/). Desktop browsers fine, but causes horizontal scrollbar to appear on iPad - and pages start sliding around. The tab has a negative absolute position (-290px,  width + padding in my css for the slide-out-div) set in the javascript. On the iPad the scrollbar takes in the width of the slide div.

```
<div class="slide-out-div">
my subscribe form
</div>

.slide-out-div {
padding: 20px;
width: 250px;
background: rgb(255,255,255);
z-index: 9999;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling
}
```

I've tried adding: -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; but doesn't seem to do anything and I'm not really sure what this would do.

Any help on fixing the scroll, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't define `overflow:hidden` to any parent container, the mobile devices expands the viewport to the size of the content. You you could go with this approach and set the `overflow` value or you can use `position: fixed` instead `absolute` on the `slide-out-div`. Both should do the trick.

Also note the text of the `<a>`-element with `text-indent: -99999px;` is "*content*", but I guess it should be "*subscribe*".

Comment: Indeed - I did try this - by adding overflow:hidden to the body element (the outermost element set to 100% width - so that the tab sticks is to the right of browser), but no luck with this. Not sure why. (PS - thanks for second note - forgot to do this)

Comment: Let me now if it worked. I can test it in the evening, when I have a cable to connect my mobile to my computer.

Comment: Yes - that works and is possibly the best compromise as I really failed to get overflow:hidden to work. I had a look around and have discovered positioning to cause interesting scoll issues on the ipad - maybe best to avoid hacking at it with this solution.